# Can I play The Division with a friend from a different continent?

Tags: the-division

For people who have owned The Division on the PS4, I had a couple of questions regarding the co-op multiplayer section

1. My friend and I stay in completely different continents. Will The Division let me play with my friend? (How do you basically initiate a co-op campaign with a particular friend?)
2. Will I be able to chat with him over microphone at all times?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I've edited your title to emphasis your main specific question, hopefully to more easily catch the eye of those who can help you with answers/comments.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Reddit post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/48wjgu/can_we_play_coop_with_people_who_are_in_different/) that answers your question.

It looks like the servers for The Division are not regionalized, so if you want to be play co-op with a friend, there shouldn't be anything stopping you from doing so.

And about the microphone/chat... I don't see why that would work differently than normal (i.e. Players in the same region). I would fully expect you to have the same chat capabilities as other players.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be absolutely fine, in my general matchmatching I seem to find a lot of Americans so there doesn't seem to be any regioning in the matchmaker (meaning it's technically fine).

As others have said, normal party chat over microphones is what me and my friends do with no problems, as a result combining these two should give you the outcome you want.